# SSRS Get first Item LookUpSet

Tags: reporting-services

So I have a dataset which contains a list of dates and foreign keys. Now I need to get the first date for a certain foreign key. I have tried the expression below:

```
=First(LookUpSet(Fields!Title.Value, Fields!Linked_Study.Value, Fields!Subject_Enrollment_Date.Value, "FPI"))
```

But it just returns *#Error*.

Does anyone know why this expression doesn't work and/or how I would be able to get the first item out of that lookupset.

If anything is still unclear please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LookUpSet() returns an array - you can simply demand the 0th item from that array by adding the suffix (0) to the LookUpSet():

```
LookUpSet(Fields!Title.Value, Fields!Linked_Study.Value, Fields!Subject_Enrollment_Date.Value, "FPI")(0)
```

EDIT: Credit to @Gravinco for pointing this out - actually using LookUp() instead of LookUpSet() will have the same effect, since this will just return the first matching value. I think that's probably a better way of doing it than my original answer.

Comment: @Gravinco - Hah. Of course it does, that's probably a better answer actually!

Comment: Yeah, I was reviewing some reports with my supervisor and he mentioned it. Thought I'd tell you in case you didn't know so maybe could update your answer?

Comment: Is there a way to make it explicitly clear what the 0th item will be? (By defining sorting?)